# What is Jonathan Mar's ethnicity?

Tags: jormungand

In the anime it is said that he is from west asia but his name doesn't sound middle eastern. More like a European.

Comment: ["A child soldier of Arabic origin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Jormungand_characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathan is a popular name in the west, but it actually originated from the middle east, that is, Israel. The first Jonathan recorded in history is the son of King Saul, first king of the Kingdom of Israel. It was recorded in the Christian Bible, a name that means "YHWH has given", with YHWH is the name of the Hebrew God.

Mar is even more Arabic as it is an honorary title in East Syriac meaning 'my lord'.

Like Hakase said in his comment, Jonathan Mar is of Arabic origin. Seeing that his name is actually from middle east, Hebrew and Syriac, it further reinforces that he is of Arabic or middle-eastern ethnicity.

You can read more about [Jonathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_(name)) and [Mar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks so much... Yeah read about it too... Its the same as Joseph.. It has hebrew/middle east origin.